# curl PUT request with --data

Tags: bash, unix, curl, http-put

I'm having a strange issue on one (and only one) computer.

Basically I'm trying to use curl to submit a PUT request and put some data to a Hue light system.

The command I'm using is:

```
curl --request PUT --data 'some data here' http://domain.example/blah
```

But I keep getting thrown the error "You can only select one HTTP request"

Is there a workaround, or a better way to do this? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: This is strange. Technically, --request selects the PUT header, --data selects the POST header. But the combination of those should be valid. On my system your request works fine. What is your output of `curl --version`?

Comment: curl 7.9.2 (powerpc-apple-freebsd) libcurl 7.9.2 (OpenSSL 0.9.6b)

:/

Comment: @nambeelr this seems to be 14-year-old version, the behavior could change. I've searched their changelog but found nothing likely concerning your problem http://curl.haxx.se/changes.html Anyway, you'd better try a newer version of curl, if that's possible.

Comment: Support for OpenSSL 0.9.6b has long ceased and it suffers from all kinds of vulnerabilities. You should better upgrade.

Comment: Wow, this may be some sort of record. We actually have fixed no less than 2515 bugs in the 86 curl releases we've done since that version.

Comment: It is a PowerMac G5 running OS X 10.5.x

Thankfully, macports helped me install a newer version of curl which fixed the problem.